# Python basemap: adjust legend height to map area

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

When plotting with basemap I can define the region where to plot the map (e.g. by `ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.05, 0.75, 0.9])`) and where to plot the legend (e.g. by `ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.05, 0.8])`). Depending on the projection and the geographical region to plot, the map will not cover the area predefined by ax1 (in my case vertical extent is much smaller then 0.9) but my legend's vertical extent is still 0.8.

When I try to get minimum and maximum y figure coordinates by transFigure.inverted to scale the legends vertical extent so that it will have the same vertical extent as the map, I will not get the proper coordinates. They are still 0.05 and 0.95, though they should be larger/smaller due to the plot.

How to get the proper extent of the map in figure coordinates ?
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.05, 0.75, 0.9])
# mp                                                                                                                                                                                                        
lon0 = 11.35
lat0 = 50.0
lon1 = 15.5
lat1 = 50.0
lon2 = 15.5
lat2 = 52.0
lon3 = 11.35
lat3 = 52.0
lat_c = (lat0 + lat2) / 2.0
lon_c = (lon0 + lon2) / 2.0
map = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0 = lat_c, lon_0 = lon_c,
resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 0.1,
llcrnrlon=lon0, llcrnrlat=lat0,
urcrnrlon=lon2, urcrnrlat=lat2)
map.drawcountries(zorder=10)
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('jet')
# get min and max value for legend test                                                                                                                                                                     
min_overall =  0.0
max_overall = 10.0

# plot blue dots for predefined map edges                                                                                                                                                                   
x0_data, y0_data = map(lon0,lat0) # lower left                                                                                                                                                              
map.plot(x0_data, y0_data, 'bo', markersize=24)
x1_data, y1_data = map(lon1,lat1) # lower right                                                                                                                                                             
map.plot(x1_data, y1_data, 'bo', markersize=24)
x2_data, y2_data = map(lon2,lat2) # upper right                                                                                                                                                             
map.plot(x2_data, y2_data, 'bo', markersize=24)
x3_data, y3_data = map(lon3,lat3) # upper left                                                                                                                                                              
map.plot(x3_data, y3_data, 'bo', markersize=24)

# convert data to display coordinates                                                                                                                                                                       
x0_y0_display = ax1.transData.transform((x0_data,y0_data))
inv_ax1_transData = ax1.transData.inverted()
x0_y0_data_test = inv_ax1_transData.transform(x0_y0_display)
x3_y3_display = ax1.transData.transform((x3_data,y3_data))

# convert display to figure coordinates                                                                                                                                                                     
inv_fig_transFigure = fig.transFigure.inverted()
x0_y0_figure = inv_fig_transFigure.transform(x0_y0_display)
x3_y3_figure = inv_fig_transFigure.transform(x3_y3_display)
print(x0_y0_figure)
print(x3_y3_figure)

# convert data to display coordinates                                                                                                                                                                       
x0_y0_display = ax1.transData.transform((x0_data,y0_data))
inv_ax1_transData = ax1.transData.inverted()
x0_y0_data_test = inv_ax1_transData.transform(x0_y0_display)
x3_y3_display = ax1.transData.transform((x3_data,y3_data))
print(x0_y0_figure)
print(x3_y3_figure)

# set colorbar                                                                                                                                                                                             
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('jet')
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.05, 0.8])
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=min_overall, vmax=max_overall)
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1, cmap=cmap,
                            norm=norm,
                            orientation='vertical')
cb1.set_label('Test')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please share all the relevant lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I did.

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems the solution seems to be quite simple:
Everything that is needed is stored in the Bbox for the first axis (ax1):
So adding to the code:

```
bb = ax1.get_position() # get Bbox from ax1
```

will give the Bbox instance for ax1, containing the edges for what is really needed to plot the map in figure coordinates

```
values_bb = bb.get_points()
```

will provide the coordinates for the Bbox edges

```
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.85, values_bb[0,1], 0.05, values_bb[1,1]-values_bb[0,1]])
```

will scale the axis for the legend to the proper vertical extent

Comment: I figured out that features described above only work properly with matplotlib3.1.1 but not with matplotlib2.1.1 where the bounding box of the map area is not properly updated.